# Amazon AWSClientFactory does not exists

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-sdk

I created an empty .Net Core application and installed nuget packages for Both Amazon.Core and Amazon.S3.

Then I tried to use S3 to get an object but I'm stuck at the very first moment... Amazon.AWSClientFactory is nowhere to be found inside the assembly. Even with dotPeek I tried to search this factory method but I couldn't find it. Even the sample code from Amazon doesn't work.

Where I supposed to find this class ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Amazon.Core and Amazon.S3 are part of the AWS SDK for .NET v3. Per the [AWS SDK for .NET Version 3 Migration Guide](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/v3-migration.html):

> Change: AWSClientFactory is removed
>
> Description: Use service client constructors instead of the AWSClientFactory

Or in other words, use IAmazonS3 and AmazonS3Client found in the Amazon.S3 nuget package:

```
using (IAmazonS3 client = new AmazonS3Client())
{
  // do stuff
}
```

### Further Reading

- [AWS Documentation - Get an Object Using the AWS SDK for .NET](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/RetrievingObjectUsingNetSDK.html)
- [AWS Documentation - AmazonS3Client](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet1/latest/apidocs/html/T_Amazon_S3_AmazonS3Client.htm)

Comment: So would it be legal for me to do something like this?             using (IAmazonS3 client = new AmazonS3Client(RegionEndpoint.USEast1))
            {

Answer (score 0):

Anthony is right. The [AWSClientFactory is removed](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/upcoming-modularization-of-the-aws-sdk-for-net/) but, remember the NuGet packages are targeted or build for the specific platform.

You will still able to use the AWSClientFactory when you set the Target Framework to 4.5.2 and install the NuGet package and when you set the Target Framework 4.0 and install the NuGet Package you will not able to use AWSCLientFactory but, instead, you can use the AmazonS3Client and write a program to work with S3.

Perhaps, understanding the .net implementation support would clarify why you faced the issue. You need to understand "The higher the version, the more APIs are available to you." Here is the [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard#net-implementation-support.) that would help you to understand the same.